isolating VM instances using subnet instead of VPCs in google cloud?
I wanted to ask if it's possible to isolate VM instances using subnets instead of creating multiple VPCs. My goal is to use a single VPC with different subnets to achieve isolation.
Due to specific requirements, I cannot create multiple VPCs and plan to rely on subnets for this purpose. However, when I attempted to attach another network interface from a different subnet, it didn't seem to work.
What would be the recommended solution in this scenario? Should I consider creating another VPC, or is there a way to accomplish this within a single VPC?
Example:
compute instance_1: 11.0.0.0/24,
compute instance_2: 11.0.1.0/24,
compute instance_3: 11.0.2.0/24,
managed mysql: 11.0.3.0/24
This doesn't work since I can only assign 1 VPC / NIC? to 1 instance.
I was hoping to assign their subnets
There's no firewall rules setup. apart from default http, https and ssh allow

Please edit your question to include a specific example with nets interfaces and firewall rules, what you expected to happen, and what did happen.
